# .htaccess rediret (match url pattern, redirect to page)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble getting this to work:

This is the original URL pattern:

- /supportcp/index.html
- /supportcp/content/edit.html
- /supportcp/members/user_banning.html
- /supportcp/*

**All should redirect to /support**

I started with the following .htaccess code but unfortunately I end up with the wrong URL.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !page=supportcp
RewriteRule ^index.php /support/ [R,L]
```

Result: /support/?/support/ (wrong)

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to append `?` in the target URI to strip off any query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !page=supportcp
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /support/? [R,NC,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It looks like this does the trick. However, now I'm encountering a redirect-loop. Here's the rest of my .htaccess file: https://gist.github.com/franzos/c9b0ba318e3c4739aec2 (Sorry, I couldn't paste it here.)

Comment: Check your full .htaccess in your answer.